# Python 3.6 tkinter says GROOVE is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter, frame, groove

The below program was working fine few minutes back. I made a change,ran the code, made a small mistake, Spyder crashed and now it either cannot find Frame or Groove or something else. At the moment it says GROOVE not defined.

Tried writing it in lower case and with quotes. When I do with quotes it says: TclError: bad relief "Groove": must be flat, groove, raised, ridge, solid, or sunken. When I do lower or upper case without quotes says groove not defined.

```
from RiskFactorConversion import *
from tkinter import ttk, StringVar, Frame, Label, Tk, Entry

mainwindow = Tk()
mainwindow.title("Risk Factor Conversion")
datatype = StringVar()
dataconvention = StringVar()
mdlname = StringVar()
instancevalue = StringVar()
axisvalue = StringVar()


def g():
    datatype = e1.get()
    dataconvention = e2.get()
    mdlname = e3.get()
    instancevalue = e4.get()
    r1 = rates.srtqualifier(mdlname,datatype,dataconvention,instancevalue)
    l5["text"] =r1.makequalifier()

def f():
    datatype = e5.get()
    dataconvention = e6.get()
    axisvalue = e8.get()
    fx1 = fx.felixfxvol(datatype,dataconvention,axisvalue)
    l11["text"] =fx1.fxvol()

def h():
    datatype = en1.get()
    dataconvention = en2.get()
    fx2 = fx.murexfx(datatype,dataconvention)
    la4["text"] =fx2.makequalifier()

#########Felix Frame####################################
frame1 = Frame(bg="white", colormap="new", padx = 10, relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=2)
frame1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
l0 = Label(frame1, text= "FELIX Rates", pady =5, font = ('Georgia',14,'bold'), bg="white")
l0.grid(row = 0, column = 0,sticky= W )
l1 = Label(frame1, text= "Please provide Data Type:",bg="white", justify = "right",pady =5 )
l1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky= E )
e1 = Entry(frame1,bd = 2, width =50, textvariable = datatype )
e1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
e1.focus_set()
l2 = Label(frame1,bg="white", text= "Please provide Data Convention:",justify = "right", pady = 5)
l2.grid(row = 2, column = 0,sticky= E)
e2 = Entry(frame1,bd = 2, width =50, textvariable = dataconvention )
e2.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
l3 = Label(frame1,bg="white", text= "Please provide Model Type:", justify = "right",pady = 5)
l3.grid(row = 3, column = 0,sticky= E)
e3 = ttk.Combobox(frame1,width =45, textvariable = mdlname, state='readonly')
e3['values'] = ('IR_SABR','FX_LN','IR_LGM','IR_LMM','IR_SABR_FX_LN_GC','IR_SABR_GC','INFLATION_SABR')
e3.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
l4 = Label(frame1,bg="white", text= "Please provide Instance Name:", justify = "right",pady = 5)
l4.grid(row = 4, column = 0,sticky= E)
e4 = Entry(frame1,bd = 2, width =50, textvariable = instancevalue )
e4.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
bfelix = Button(frame1, text = "Press to get Qualifier Value", pady = 10, command = g)
bfelix.grid(row = 5, column = 0)
l5 = Label(frame1,bg="white", text= "" , justify = "right",pady = 5)
l5.grid(row = 5, column = 1)
################################################################

############FELIX FX############################################
frame2 = Frame(bg="white", colormap="new", padx = 10, relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=2)
frame2.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
l6 = Label(frame2, text= "FELIX FX", pady =5, font = ('Georgia',14,'bold'), bg="white")
l6.grid(row = 0, column = 0,sticky= W )
l7 = Label(frame2, text= "Please provide Data Type:",bg="white", justify = "right",pady =5 )
l7.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky= E )
e5 = Entry(frame2,bd = 2, width =50, textvariable = datatype)
e5.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
e5.focus_set()
l8 = Label(frame2,bg="white", text= "Please provide Data Convention:",justify = "right", pady = 5)
l8.grid(row = 2, column = 0,sticky= E)
e6 = Entry(frame2,bd = 2, width =50, textvariable = dataconvention )
e6.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
l10 = Label(frame2,bg="white", text= "Please provide axis 2 value:", justify = "right",pady = 5)
l10.grid(row = 3, column = 0,sticky= E)
e8 = Entry(frame2,bd = 2, width =50, textvariable = axisvalue )
e8.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
bfelixfx = Button(frame2, text = "Press to get Qualifier Value", pady = 10, command = f)
bfelixfx.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
l11 = Label(frame2,bg="white", text= "" , justify = "right",pady = 5)
l11.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
#####################################################################

############MUREX FX############################################
frame3 = Frame(bg="white", colormap="new", padx = 10, relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=2)
frame3.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
la = Label(frame3, text= "Murex FX", pady =5, font = ('Georgia',14,'bold'), bg="white")
la.grid(row = 0, column = 0,sticky= W )
la1 = Label(frame3, text= "Please provide Risk Factor Type:",bg="white", justify = "right",pady =5 )
la1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky= E )
en1 = ttk.Combobox(frame3, width =45, textvariable = mdlname, state='readonly')
en1['values'] =('FX ATM VOLATILITY','FX BUTTERFLY 10D','FX BUTTERFLY 25D','FX RISK REVERSAL 10D','FX RISK REVERSAL 25D')
en1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
en1.focus_set()
la2 = Label(frame3,bg="white", text= "Please provide Currency Pair:",justify = "right", pady = 5)
la2.grid(row = 2, column = 0,sticky= E)
en2 = Entry(frame3,bd = 2, width =50, textvariable = dataconvention )
en2.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
bmurexfx = Button(frame3, text = "Press to get Qualifier Value", pady = 10, command = h)
bmurexfx.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
la4 = Label(frame3,bg="white", text= "" , justify = "right",pady = 5)
la4.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
#####################################################################




mainwindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: use `print(tk.GROOVE)` and you will see text `"groove"`. You can use text `relief="groove"` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groove is a constant defined in Tkinter and since you are only importing specfic functions from Tkinter that doesn't include Groove, you need to add GROOVE to it or add

```
import tkinter as tk
```

and then set relief=tk.GROOVE

Comment: That makes complete sense! in the second line I imported GROOVE and other functions it runs now. But may I ask another question, when I close my program it crashes with saying Tk_GetColorFromObj called with non‑existent color!
Is it possible to do something that this doesn't happen?

Comment: groove is not a function. `GROOVE` is a constant defined in tkinter.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, I changed it in my answer.